# Is there a way of installing Windows without a Drive C

Tags: windows, installation

Is it possible to create an installation of Windows where there is no drive C? I've tried a number of approaches with having blank disks and other things, but never managed to get it to work.

I'm trying to reproduce an environment a customer has where installing software fails because there is no drive C.

Comment: What kind of drives do you have?

Comment: Testing with a virtual pc. I'm not sure what the customer has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223188) tells you how to change the drive letter of the system drive after windows is installed, this should do what you want. The article is for changing from D to C, but will work the other way as well.

Comment: This also happens with Citrix.  Citrix used to install the system drive as the "M" drive if I remember right. Ran into this problem all the time.

Comment: Our Citrix environment installs to drive Q, but I don't know if that's something specified at install or not.

Answer (score 1):

When installing windows, delete any existing partitions on the disk.
Create 2 (or more new partitions) the first partition you create should be labelled as C: the second D: etc.
Select to install windows to the second partition. Proceed with installation as normal.
WHen installation is completed, open up Local DIsk Managment (diskmgmt.msc) and delete your C: partition (which may not even be formatted)

Job Done.

Comment: I've tried that before, but when I deleted drive C, the old drive D became drive C

Comment: was that when you installed windows or when you were still on the blue partitioning screen? What Version? Server 2003/Vista/XP?

Answer (score 0):

Separate drive in two partitions. Install windows on first one. Install second windows on second one. In boot menu (will be set by second windows install) boot second windows. It will live on drive "D:" :)